# all subsets of R are reflexive?

Tags: relations

Prove or refute:

- If R is reflexive than all subsets of R are reflexive.

This my solution:

Let {1,2,3) in R --> We know that R is reflexive -> R = {*(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),*(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),*(3,3)}. We also know that R subset means: R is a set which all the elements are contained in another set, which means there are also reflexive.

Not sure if correct or totally wrong, please need help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It appears that you don't know what "reflexive" means.  You might want to learn that first: it might be helpful in proving that other sets are reflexive :).

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you are wrong. The answer is no. Counterexample is:

set $X = \mathbb{N}$, and $R\subseteq P(X\times X)$

$R = \lbrace(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)\rbrace$.

Of course $R$ is reflexive, because $xRx$ holds for every $x\in X$.

Now we can take a subset of $R$, for example $R_1 = \lbrace(1,2), (2,1)\rbrace$.

It is easy to see that $R_1$ is not reflexive.